# Get values from deeply nested object

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am working to get values from deeply nested object. The data and expected output are below. I got this data like below from request of API.

I have to use this script at Google Apps Script. So please note I cannot use ECMAScript6.

**Object**

```
var obj = {
  "key1": [
    {
      "key2": [
        {
          "key3": {
            "key4": {
              "key5": [
                {
                  "key6": "value6"
                },
                {},
                {
                  "key7": {
                    "key8": "value8"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key3": {
            "key4": {
              "key5": [
                {
                  "key6": "value6"
                },
                {
                  "key7": {
                    "key8": "value8"
                  }
                },
                {}
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key3": {
            "key5": "value5"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "key2": [
        {
          "key3": {
            "key4": {
              "key5": [
                {
                  "key6": "value6"
                },
                {
                  "key7": {
                    "key8": "value8"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key3": {
            "key4": {
              "key5": [
                {
                  "key6": "value6"
                },
                {},
                {
                  "key7": {
                    "key8": "value8"
                  }
                },
                {}
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key3": {
            "key5": "value5"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

**Expected output**

I want values of "key8".

```
value8
value8
value8
value8
```

**My current script**

```
for (var i in obj.key1) {
  for (var j in obj.key1[i].key2) {
    for (var k in obj.key1[i].key2[j].key3.key4.key5[k]) {
      Logger.log(obj.key1[i].key2[j].key3.key4.key5[k].key7.key8)
    }
  }
}
```

**Error message**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property "key5" from undefined.
```

This error is at

```
for (var k in json.key1[i].key2[j].key3.key4.key5[k]) {
```

My questions are

- What is reason of error?
- How modify should I my script to get values of "key8"?

### Updated

I got 2 solutions of my question.

**One is**

```
var result = [];
for (var i in obj.key1) {
  for (var j in obj.key1[i].key2){
    if (obj.key1[i].key2[j].key3.key4) {
      for (var k in obj.key1[i].key2[j].key3.key4.key5) {
        if (obj.key1[i].key2[j].key3.key4.key5[k].key7) {
          result.push(obj.key1[i].key2[j].key3.key4.key5[k].key7.key8);
        }
      }
    } else {
      continue;
    }
  }
}
Logger.log(result) // >>> [value8, value8, value8, value8]
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lxa8tsfb/

**Another is**

```
var result = function () {
  var result = [];
  (function traverse(obj) {
    if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
      obj.forEach(traverse);
    } else if (typeof obj === 'object') {
      Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
        if (key === 'key8') {
          result.push(obj[key]);
        } else {
          traverse(obj[key]);
        }
      });
    }
  }(obj));
  return result;
}();
Logger.log(result) // >>> [value8, value8, value8, value8]
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ffuuur0L/

1st one is my answer. 2nd one is an answer by @Petr. My answer can use only when users know the structure of object. Petr's answer can use when users know the key. I think Petr's answer is useful. So I accepted Petr's answer.

Comment: firstly, that's not JSON - that's a javascript Object - perhaps that will help you search for the right documentation

Comment: @Jaromanda X Thank you for taking your time. I didn't know that is not JSON. What should I do to get values? By the way should I remove a word of JSON from title of question and tag?

Comment: please add if the objects depth is always the same and if the keys are the same and the structure (objects/arrays) is the same and if the target key is the same.

Comment: @Cerbrus Thank you for editing.

Comment: No problem. I'm pretty sure there's a duplicate out there that solves this. Couldn't find it yet though... Nevermind, there we go :D

Comment: @Nina Scholz Thank you for taking your time. When I use such object, when I use as JSON after modified object, is it easy to use?

Comment: @Cerbrus Thank you for the information.

Comment: @Cerbrus, the dupe target handles only arrays, but not nested objects.

Comment: Then I'm sure there's a better target out there...

Comment: Are you still looking for the solution?

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you. My problem still haven't been solved. But I want to find it from comments.

Comment: @Nina Scholz Thank you very much for your comment. I could get solutions.

Comment: @Cerbrus Thank you very much for your comment. I could get solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use recursion here, something like this:

```
function traverse(json) {
    if (Array.isArray(json)) {
        json.forEach(traverse);
    } else if (typeof json === 'object') {
        Object.keys(json).forEach(function(key) {
            if (key === 'key8') {
                console.log(json[key]);
            } else {
               traverse(json[key]);
            }
        });
    }
};

traverse(json);
```

This code is obviously imperfect, you might want to make `key8` a parameter and wrap this into some method with a better name, but it works.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time. I could find values at ``console.log(json[key])``. Can you return all values to outside of ``traverse(json)``?

Comment: @NinaScholz: `typeof json === 'object'` has that covered. This answer will not traverse strings.

Comment: @Cerbrus, right but no not `null` check.

Comment: The missing null check doesn't validate your previous comment. That's completely different.

Comment: Petr, add this at the start of your function: `if(!json)return;`

Comment: I got 2 solutions. But I think your answer is better than mine. I accepted your answer. Thank you very much. I have one question. Your answer is your original? If you refered to other user's answer, can I ask you about the URL? I want to upvote it.